# Multiple parameters on DRF ModelViewset Destroy Method

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to remove a product from certain user's wishlist. I have tried using ModelViewSet's destroy method for this but of course failed. The thing is, I need to send two parameters to my destroy method, so a generic view wouldn't work. Any way to approach this problem?

This is what I tried to do:

```
class WishlistViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = WishlistSerializer

# get_queryset and create methods here

def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    post_data = request.data

    selected_user = User.objects.get(pk=int(post_data['user_id']))
    selected_producto = Catalogo.objects.get(pk=int(post_data['producto_id']))

    product_in_wishlist = Wishlist.objects.get(id_catalogo_producto=selected_producto, id_cliente=selected_user)
    product_in_wishlist.delete()

    return Response({'message': 'Producto eliminado de tu lista de deseos'})
```

This is my urls.py for this app:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('wishlist', WishlistViewSet, basename='wishlist')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**Solution**

Turns out that the approach that best worked for me is to first, do a get request, to obtain the wishlist row id. Then, doing a delete request with this ID worked perfectly.

Comment: What is the result you get with your code?

Comment: "detail": "Method \"DELETE\" not allowed." This is because my url type doesnt support delete method, which is a Router with the Viewsets registered. But I cant find an approach on DRF documentation either.

Comment: Can you share the relevant `urls.py`? please

Comment: Done my friend.

Comment: Can you send other requests to the endpoint, like `GET`?

Comment: Yes. Get and Post is working, but Delete no because of the url type, which in this case is /store/wishlist/.

Comment: `DELETE` is a verb which operates on a url, in your case `/wishlist/<int:id>/` as provided by with ViewSet.  What you want to do here is simply POST some data to an endpoint, which is not the correct  usage of the `destroy` method.   Maybe you an use an `@action` on the viewset, creating `/wishlist/remove/` and passing the expected request, and you can even validate it using a serializer in the method.